# JFrame does not appear

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm using the Intelij idea platform.

I have the following code:

```
package GUI.test;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame{

         Frame(){}

public void main (String[] args){

    new Frame();
}

}
```

I expected to see a JFrame after compiling this code, but was nothing appeared. What kind of problem can it be?

Comment: Please read this basic tutorial on how to create a frame: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

Comment: Don't use "Frame" as the class names. That is an AWT component so it can be a little confusing to use that name. The class name should be more descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to add this

```
Frame()
  {
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(100,100);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Frames are not visible by default--use the

```
setVisible(true);
```

method in order to display frames.
You also might want to take a look at other options such as

```
setSize(int width, int height);
```

method to resize a frame,

```
setLocation(int xLoc, int yLoc);
```

to move the frame, and

```
setTitle(String title);
```

to set the title of the component.

Aside, it is good practice to use a variable to hold components so they can be manipulated when needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
package GUI.test;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame{
private myFrame;

public Frame()
{
 myFrame = new JFrame("put a title here");   //title not necessary but it's there if you want it
 myFrame.setSize(400,400); // sets the window size
 myFrame.setVisible(true); // toggles the frame to be visible inside the window
 myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); // this will terminate the VM once the *last* JFrame is closed, so you can have multiple frames open and just close one
}

public void main (String[] args){

    new Frame();
}

}
```

Comment: also, note that the java API has a class called "Frame" already, so it's best to rename your class to something other than Frame.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for answering. I wrote an example without details. I have added:    setVisible(true);
setSize(100,100);

to a class constructor. But i havent seen form jet.

Have to say about one feature. I'm not running method main in class Frame, i'm compiling this class Frame. In my previous exersises with java i allways run main method, but when i tried to work with GUI form and used swing library, ability to run method main have dissapiared.

If you haven't cought what i mean, i'd send a screenshot.